# Dynamic Updates and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this...

`<script> var num = 22;</script>`

Then inside of the controller block...

```
<span>{{somenumber}}</span>
```

In the controller...

```
$scope.somenumber = num;
```

This all works as expected.

How would I go about having it all update if the value of the num variable changes?  So, I'd have some code (from socket.io or AJAX) change num to 65.  Right now, it still says 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

`num` is a primitive type (Number). So When you're assigning it to the `$scope` you're copying it. What you need to do is *reference* it instead. I'd fix it the following way.

```
<script>var value = {num: 22} </script>

$scope.value = value;

<span> {{value.num}} </span>
```

If your ajax call is not through `$http`.(outside angular - wherever you set `value.num`) you'll need to invoke a digest cycle. The easiest way to do that is in an angular service like `$timeout`.

Think of the scope as

> `$scope`*HAS* model instead of `$scope`*AS* model

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) followed by [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

**Controller**

```js
$scope.somenumber = num;

$scope.$watch(function() {
  return num;
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.somenumber = newValue;
});

// fake external change to the 'num' variable
setTimeout(function() {
  num = 33;
  $scope.$apply();
}, 3000);
```

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rL20lyI1SgS6keFbckJp?p=preview

---

If your external change is happening outside the scope of a single controller, I would use `$rootScope` inside a `run` callback:

```js
angular.module('exampleApp', []).run(function($rootScope) {
    // same as above, just with $rootScope
});
```